# HTML5 - iOS 11+ hide video controlls

Tags: ios, css, html, web

I am trying to remove "play" button from video. Below is my code:

```
<video class="video" autoplay muted loop playsinline poster="video.gif">
   <source src="video.mp4" />
</video>
```

As attribute "controls" is boolean I don't see them on Chrome, Firefox, IE and Android browsers - so it's ok.
But they still appeared on Safari. This piece of code removed "play" button on iOS 9.4.

```
.video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    display: none!important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.video::--webkit-media-controls-play-button {
    display: none!important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
    display: none!important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

But it still appears on iOS 11.2.

Do you have any idea how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

you can use javascript to disable it.

```
document.getElementById("herePutVideoId").controls = false;
```